# Windows Azure or RackSpace Cloud?

Tags: web-applications, hosting, azure, cloud

So I have been running the numbers for Azure and RackSpace Cloud Servers and found that RackSpace is substantially cheaper, less developer investment (no custom programming), and RackSpace offers RackSpace Cloud Files if you need a substantial storage solution for your site.  It almost seems too good to be true, what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazon?

See: http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/ and http://aws.amazon.com/s3/

Pricing: http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/#pricing and http://aws.amazon.com/s3/#pricing

Comment: hmmm, it is cheaper...I will take a look...

Answer (score 6):

I've been using RackSpace cloud rather than Amazon because for small instances RS is less expensive. The service has been rock solid.

Answer (score 5):

Another platform you should check out is [AppHarbor](http://appharbor.com/). AppHarbor is a PaaS built on top of Amazon. On the one hand you get the portability and infrastructure of Amazon but on the other they provide a number of the rich services that Azure offers such as background tasks & load balancing plus some that it doesn't like 3rd party add-ons, dead-simple deployment and more.

Answer (score 5):

In response to the person above who recommended Amazon ...

I personally use Amazon EC2, but I run Linux. I was exploring these options for a friend of mine and I came to the conclusion that Rackspace is a better deal than Amazon for Windows.

The reason is that Amazon's pricing will put you at $3000+ a year for a reserved instance if you want SQL Server (which you can only get on a "large" instance or bigger). Sure, you could get SQL Server Express at no extra cost, but it has a limit of 4GB which is quite a constraint.

On the other hand, Rackspace lets you get SQL Server on a 2048MB instance for about $160 a month, meaning it's about half the price of the large instance at Amazon. The reason it's so cheap is because 2048MB is much smaller than the "large" EC2 instance (which is 8GB). Additionally, Rackspace lets you choose SQL Server Web edition which is much cheaper than Standard Edition which is the only thing Amazon offers.

In summary: If you're deciding between EC2 and Rackspace, go with Rackspace if you're an individual or a small company because it's much cheaper. However, if you need a lot of computing power, EC2 is still cheaper pound-for-pound.

Answer (score 4):

You need to analyze your application and see which cloud computing / storage platform will be the best fit for it. Rackspace has a very handy API that you can use to [manage your cloud](http://devguide.net/books/rackspacecloudservers), which may be but doesn't have to be a deciding factor. Rackspace has persistent instances, which means you don't have to worry so much about instance crashes and you don't have to engineer a custom solution like you have to do with Amazon AWS. The Amazon advantage is the richness on their custom services, but if you decide to use them, you will be locked into their infrastructure. It is similar thing with Windows Azure. This is being addressed by the OpenStack project. Do your research, the price lists don't tell the whole story.

Answer (score 2):

How come is Rackspace cheaper? that's only if you need Web hosting. Adding a SQL Server database to your cloud server adds $500 to your monthly fee (72cents/hour)

I am actually trying to find which one is better, too. However I think I will go with Azure, since it has a $109 plan which includes SQL Azure
;)

Comment: Rack Space is cheaper because for my applications don't require RS to pay Microsoft in order for them to run.